# Change the frequency that outlook checks for updates

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I've recently started using the Outlook preview in Windows 11 (Outlook version 1.2023.816.100), and I get daily notifications that 'An update is available -- Click to restart'.

Frankly, I'd like to see a bit less of this. Updating once a week would be fine, but I can't find anywhere to change this. If 'Customize' under notifications nor 'Settings' on the title bar have any way to change this, I haven't found it.

Is this something that I can change, and if so, how?

Comment: The update options are contained within Outlook and other Office products. Switch channels and you’ll avoid the daily prompts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preview and Insider updates come frequently and unannounced . I have a machine for Insider and Preview work.

If you do not wish the frequency, then remove yourself from the Preview program. Production Outlook works fine in this respect.

There is no native way to adjust the frequency of Preview / Insider updating.